# How can I better organize my code in C#?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'm writing my first ever GUI and my first program in C#.  My GUI has dozens of menu options, most of which have very simplistic routines like

```
private void menuItem54_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  button1.Text = menuItem54.Text;
  functionFoo(menuItem54.Text);
}
```

So my question is, can I somehow place all of these functions in another file and include them in my main program?  That why my main .cs file isn't cluttered?  Thank you!

Comment: always give your controls meaningful names -- avoid using the assigned defaults (button1, menuItem54)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

just do basic OOP and create class file based on object.

You can learn more about [OOP and SOLID Principle here.](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod)

So for your example, maybe you can create an interface for the menu.

and create different menu object which uses the same interface.

```
public interface IMenu{
string functionFoo();
}

public class Menu54 : IMenu {
public string Text { get; set;}
public string functionFoo(){
return Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may think about MVVM pattern for your application. Read more: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

Comment: You don't refer MVVM to someone who is writing his *first ever GUI and first program in C#*